# How to async/await in onPress confirmation Alert?

Tags: react-native

I need to delete an account when user confirms the Alert.

I tried using async/await directly to the confirm onPress but I receive an error `Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):`

```js
const DeleteAccount = () => {
  Alert.alert(
    "Delete account",
    "If you delete your account, You will lose your current data",
    [
      {
        text: "Cancel"
      },
      {
        text: "Delete",
        onPress: async() => await deleteteUserApi(auth),
      }
    ],
    {
      cancelable: false,
    }
  )
}
```

```js
<List.Item
  title="Delete my account"
  description="Delete account permanetly"
  left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="delete" />}
  onPress={DeleteAccount}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s possible to use `async` fonction on the `Alert` `onPress` option.

Looks like the problem is coming from the function itself. Try to catch errors to see what’s happening:

```js
// ..
onPress: async () => { 
  try {
    await deleteteUserApi(auth)
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
}
// ..
```